# There is a typo in the text of the site's tour: "Portugese"

Tags: bug, status-completed

In https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/tour

> Portugese linguistics, orthography, or etymology

It should be written `Portuguese`, with u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one I could fix. Let us know if you find any more.

[image: Portuguese]