# $Topic should be "Portuguese language" not "portuguese language"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I don't mean to be nitpicking, but [while we're talking about typos of the word "Portuguese"](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/187/64), the off-topic close reason reads

[image: small p]

where "portuguese language" seems to correspond to `$Topic`. I don't know if `$Topic` is used elsewhere, but if so, it should be "Portuguese language" with a capital P.

---

**Solved**. Now `This question does not appear to be about the $Topic` renders correctly:

[image: off-topic]

Comment: Note that mortal users *might* have never seen this "$Topic" you speak of, and *might* have a very feeble grasp of the concept.

Comment: @ANeves Fine. `$Topic` seems to be a variable used by the Stack Exchange API, which is used in the off-topic close reason. Ask your friendly programming neighbour for more info. (And note that I don't understand the meaning of variable, API and programming...)